# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'original')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, components

When creating a simple training project, an error flies into me.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'original')
    at Character (Character.js:7:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1)
```

Moreover, if you quickly refresh the page, you can see the images with which the error occurs, and links to the images are working.

Fake API when I took date

> https://api.tvmaze.com/characters/1

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Character from "./components/Character";

function App() {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      characterFetch(i);
    }
  }, []);

  async function characterFetch(id) {
    fetch("https://api.tvmaze.com/characters/" + id)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) =>
        setCharacters((lastcharacters) => [...lastcharacters, json])
      );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {characters.map((character) => {
        return <Character character={character} key={character.id} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Character.js

```
import React from "react";

const Character = (props) => {
  if (props.character.name !== "Not Found") {
    var construct = (
      <>
        <img src={props.character.image.original} alt="Character_photo" />  //error
        <div> {props.character.id} </div>
        <div>{props.character.name}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
  return <div>{construct}</div>;
};

export default Character;
```

Comment: Clearly, for at least one of the characters, `character.image` is `null`. A quick check just told me ther eare **lots** of those. https://api.tvmaze.com/characters/38 for instance.

Comment: `<img src={props.character.image?.original} alt="Character_photo" />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some of the characters, the `image` is `null`.

**Example:** https://api.tvmaze.com/characters/15

That's why you are getting as

```
Cannot read properties of null
```

To fix it, you can use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
or check with a simple `if else`

**Example:**

```js
props.character.image?.original
```